# Visual Studio Load Test request completion and think time

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I'm using load test in Visual Studio to test our web api services. But to my surprise I can't seem to test what I want to.  Actually  I have a single url in my .webtest file and try to send the same url time and again to see what is the avg. response time. 
Here are the details

```
1.I use constant load of 1 user
2.Test duration of  1 hour
3.Think time of 10 seconds (not the think time between iterations)
4.The avg. response time that I get is 1.5 seconds
5.So the avg. test time comes out to be 11.5 seconds
6.Requests/sec are 0.088
7.And I'm using Sequential Test Order among 4 types of different tests
```

So these figures are making me think that every time a virtual user sends a request besides the specified think time it waits for the request to complete before he sends a new one (request). Thus technically the total think time becomes

Total think time  = think time specified + avg. response time

But I don't want the user to wait for an already sent request to come back and then send a new one  after a specified think time. I need to configure the load test in such a way that if the think time is 10 seconds then the user should send next request after every 10 seconds without waiting the first one to come back then think for another 10 seconds and then send a new request (hence making the total think time to 11.5 seconds in my case as mentioned above). And no matter what type of test I choose among 4 different types Visual Studio is always forcing the virtual user to wait for the completion of the request then add specified think time and then send a new one.

I know what Visual Studio load test is doing is more of a practical approach where the user sends the request wait till it comes back then think or interact with the website and then sends a new one.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated towards what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Has your question been answered? If yes then please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer . If it is not answered then please explain what else is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of the scenario, set the "Test mix type" to be "Test mix based on user pace" and set the "Tests per user per hour" as appropriate. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514186.aspx#PacingTestMix).

The suggestion in the question that:

> Total think time = think time specified + avg. response time

is erroneous. To my mind adding the values does not provide a useful result. The two values on the right are as stated. Think time simulates the time a user spends reading the page, deciding what to do next and typing/clicking/etc their response. Response time is the "turn around" time between sending a request and getting the response. Adding them does not increase the think time in any sense, it just makes the total duration for handing the request *in this specific test*. Another test might make the same request with a different think time. Note that many web pages cause more than one request and response to be issued; JavaScript and other allow web pages to do many clever things.

Comment: I know what you mean but when i say total think time = think time specified + avg. response time, i don't literally mean that there is any entity called total think time as such it's just my way of perceiving it i.e. the time that a user spends  interacting/reading/clicking (on a web page) plus the round trip time of a response adds up and then visual studio issues new request on behalf of a virtual user. More so when I tried the "Test mix based on user pace" for 4 virtual users' constant load what Visual Studio is doing that it calculates 4 x (think time + avg.response time)  time .

Comment: And after that calculated time then its starts the next iteration for subsequent load i.e. it sends the requests from all 4 users and waits for all 4 users to get the responses back and only then iterates again. Where as I specified that 2000 Tests per user per hour should happen but visual studio after calculating a "number" as mentioned in above comment 4 x (think time + avg.response time) says that 2000 test per user per hour is way too much when the avg. test time is 4.57 seconds. And these 4.57 seconds nothing but  this value 4 x (think time + avg.response time)  where think time is 0.

Comment: in this test. In other words Visual Studio is not letting me do 2000 tests per user per hour rather it controls my tests on its own and sees that a single load with 4 constant users will take 4.57 seconds per iteration (time spent in sending requests and getting back responses for all 4 users) for a single load and then starts issuing new requests for a new load which is not letting me achieve my goal of 2000 tests per user per hour mark.

Comment: @user2913184 Please edit your original question to explain what you want to do. You have explained what you did and some of what happened but you have not said what you want. Please also read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I'm not sure shall I edit my question or not, but here is what I wanted after doing an experiment with both types of tests viz. sequential  test and user pace.  As far as user pace test is concerned I want that if I put constant load of 4 users and a 2000 tests per user per hour Visual Studio shall not wait for all the 4 users to get their responses back in a given load test iteration and then supply a set of new requests for all 4 user in subsequent load test iteration. I want no matter what Visual Studio shall supply 4 requests in parallel and shouldn't wait for the responses to come back.

Comment: Rather should supply another 4 requests in parallel (for 4 virtual users) for next load iteration and keep on doing so until I achieve my figure of 2000 tests per user per hour

Comment: @user2913184 If your question does not explain what you want to do then it is very difficult for anyone else to provide an answer.